# Remixd won't install: chokidar errors

Tags: remix, installation

I am trying to install remixd on mac, but get this error:

```
glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: high
Regular expression denial of service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6
No fix available
node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/chokidar
    @remix-project/remixd  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/@remix-project/remixd

3 high severity vulnerabilities
```

Would it make sense for me to upgrade the webpack-dev-server? I am new to this and don't want to mess up my computer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to install but know, fixing or upgrading to new packages could make your projects fail if you require a specific version in your existing project as items could become deprecated version to version.

Comment: So its not unsafe to go ahead with using remixd despite the flags?